# Ecore - Is there a way to refer an ecore metamodel from another ecore metamodel?

Tags: eclipse, ecore

I have two meta-models lets say A.ecore and B.ecore,

What I want to achieve is that, element A from A.core should contain(or reference) element B from B.ecore. So that I can link two metamodels and can provide ATL rules using these two meta-models like they are one meta-model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the "Sample Ecore Model Editor", right click anywhere > Load Resource ... and browse accordingly to your other ecore.